# nested loop to convert multidimensional array into a Hashmap

Tags: java, loops

I would like to convert the following multidimensional array

```
[[ChestPain, (Chest), Heartburn], [Day2NumberofRefluxes, 2, 1, 5], [SIDay2, 15.4, 3.8, 71.4], [SAPDay2, 70.2, 0.0, 99.9]]
```

into a HashMap as follows

```
mapReflDayOneandTwo{Day2NumberofRefluxesChestPain=2, Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=1, Day2NumberofRefluxesHeartburn=5, SIDay2ChestPain=15.4, SIDay2(Chest)=3.8, SIDay2Heartburn=71.4, SAPDay2ChestPain=70.2, SAPDay2(Chest)=0.0, SAPDay2Heartburn=99.9}
```

I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
for (int ff=1;ff<Symptoms.size();ff++){
         for (int fx=0;fx<Symptoms.get(0).size();fx++){
             for (int fxr=1;fxr<Symptoms.get(fx).size();fxr++){
             mapReflDayOneandTwo.put(Symptoms.get(ff).get(0)+Symptoms.get(0).get(fx),Symptoms.get(ff).get(fxr));
                                                              } 
                                                       }
                                       }
```

However when I do this the values seem to be incorrect and I get the following results with the values associated with the wrong keys. What am I doing wrong in the loop? (and shifting the ff to start at 0 or fxr to start at 0 doesn't work either)

```
mapReflDayOneandTwo{Day2NumberofRefluxesChestPain=1, Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=5, Day2NumberofRefluxesHeartburn=5, SIDay2ChestPain=3.8, SIDay2(Chest)=71.4, SIDay2Heartburn=71.4, SAPDay2ChestPain=0.0, SAPDay2(Chest)=99.9, SAPDay2Heartburn=99.9}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, you have 3 loops so you will combine everything with everything (but you will see only the final result, since in map, old combos are overwritten). What you do is, for example, combine `(Chest)` with `Day2NumberofRefluxes` 3 times, but only one result will stay in the map, the wrong one:

1. values of `for` variables will be `1, 1, 1`, so you place value `Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=2` in the map
2. values of `for` variables will be `1, 1, 2`, so you place value `Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=1` in the map
3. values of `for` variables will be `1, 1, 3`, so you place value `Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=5` in the map

So you are left with `Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=5` in the map.

You need only 2 `for` loops, first to go through first list, and second one to go through other lists in the matrix, so when you combine `(Chest)` with `Day2NumberofRefluxes`, in that moment you know coordinates of their combo value `(i,j + 1)`, and you place that value in the map:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < Symptoms.get(0).size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < Symptoms.size(); j ++) {
            mapReflDayOneandTwo.put(Symptoms.get(j).get(0) + Symptoms.get(0).get(i), 
                 Symptoms.get(j).get(i + 1));
        }
   }
```

Now you get:

```
{Day2NumberofRefluxes(Chest)=1, Day2NumberofRefluxesChestPain=2, Day2NumberofRefluxesHearthburn=5, SAPDay2(Chest)=0.0, SAPDay2ChestPain=70.2, SAPDay2Hearthburn=99.9, SIDay2(Chest)=3.8, SIDay2ChestPain=15.4, SIDay2Hearthburn=71.4}
```

Comment: If I shift them back to 0 I get the following output: HeartburnHeartburn  Heartburn,
HeartburnHeartburn  (Chest),
HeartburnHeartburn  ChestPain,
Heartburn(Chest)  Heartburn,
Heartburn(Chest)  (Chest),
Heartburn(Chest)  ChestPain,

Comment: OK. Perfect. Thanks so much